# Populate Angular Dropdown from Laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I have dropdown on my blade template which I would like to populate on page load.
I am getting the data from DB using Laravel and this is how the result is returned when I log the output to console.
[image]

The angular code I have on my page is this,
[image]

Though the values are returned, my dropdown is still empty. Can someone please assist.
[image]

Here is my angular controller,
[image]

Comment: Please edit you question to add code blocks rather than images.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-options` should be as:

```
<select ng-model="cmbSchema" ng-options="t as t.table_schema for t in schemalist track by $index">
```

See [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)